# Best-practice - @font-face normal/bold/heavy

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've got a question considering the @font-face command to add custom fonts to a webpage via CSS.

I've always used @font-face like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    src: url('url-to-font') [eot, woff, ttf, ...];
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont-Bold", [Fallbacks...];
    src: url('url-to-font') [eot, woff, ttf, ...];
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

* {
    font-family: "MyFont", [Fallbacks...]
}

h1 {
    font-family: "MyFont-Bold", [Fallbacks...];
}
```

There a two things: Is it okay to use the wildcard selector (*) to apply a font-face to the entire page? Are there better ways?

Is it possible to omit:

```
font-family: "MyFont-Bold";
```

and instead say:

```
font-family: "MyFont";
font-weight: bold;
```

And if yes, is doing so any good?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd usually do this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    src: url('font-regular.woff'); /* note filename */
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    src: url('font-bold.woff'); /* note different filename */
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "MyFont", [Fallbacks...];
    font-weight: 700; /* automatically picks the bold flavour now */
}
```

Comment: Please let me add this reading for anyone coming to this question on the future
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/setting-weights-and-styles-at-font-face-declaration/